# Client not receiving data from server

Tags: python-2.7

Please, by executing a code (which I can't publish beacause it contains more than 3000 lines), I realized that sometimes the client does not receive the data from the server, and yet the client is alwayslistening, do you have an idea about the various causes please ??

Ps: sometime it workswell, but somtimes not, I searched everywhere and nothing worked.

Thank you very much.

Comment: more details (protocol, etc), minimum example?

Comment: Hi W.Mann, I used tcp, and when the server send data for a group of client, if we have 6 clients only 3 will receive it

Comment: sometimes only 1 won't receive the data, i thought it was because i put s.listen(number) out of the while 1 but it wasn't the reason :s

Answer (score 0):

Here is the socket side of the client, knowing that the client can also be server

```
def run(self):

    HOST = ''                
    PORT = self.val     
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind((HOST, PORT)
    s.listen(300000)
    while 1:
        conn, addr = s.accept()

        data = conn.recv(4096)

        if not data:
            break
    conn.shutdown(1)
    conn.close()
```